# Pasar un parametro a una función desde un for loop JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, web, bucle-for

Este es parte de mi código:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    miFuncion(i);
}

function miFuncion(i){
var miVentana = window.open("", "miVentana", "width=200,height=100");
miVentana.document.write("Esta es la ventana número " + i);
}
```

Quiero que se abran tres ventanas diferentes, cada una con el texto que le corresponde pero por alguna razón siempre sale "Esta es la ventana número 3". 
No sé por qué no se abre una en cada ciclo del loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta esto:

```js
var configuracion_ventana = "menubar=yes,location=yes,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,status=yes";

function miFuncion(i) {
  let ventana = window.open("", "Mi Ventana"+i, configuracion_ventana);
  ventana.document.write("Esta es la ventana número " + i);
}                                                                         

// Llamamos a la función
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++){
 miFuncion(i);
}
```